# Replacing conditional chains of type checking

Tags: c#

I stumbled across some code today that looked similar to:

```
  if (myObject is MyClass1) 
     myOtherObject = new MyOtherClass1(myObject);
  else if (myObject  is MyClass2) 
     myOtherObject = new MyOtherClass2(myObject);
  else if (myObject  is MyClass3)
     myOtherObject = new MyOtherClass3(myObject);
  else if (myObject  is MyClass4)
     myOtherObject = new MyOtherClass4(myObject);
  else if (myObject  is MyClass5)
     myOtherObject = new MyOtherClass5(myObject);
  else if (myObject  is MyClass6) 
     // ...
```

I find this somewhat difficult to maintain and would like to replace it with something less cumbersome. What are my options?

So far I've considered a table driven approach using a dictionary but I'm not sure if that's the best option.

```
// Not even sure this is valid syntax.
foreach (myClass in classes)
   if myObject is myClass
      new classes[myClass](myObject);
```

Any other ideas?

**Update**

Without going into to many details here is the basic structure of the classes:

```
MyBaseClass                              MyOtherBaseClass
  |                                        |
   -MyClass1                                -MyOtherClass1
  |                                        |
   -MyClass2                                -MyOtherClass2
```

MyBaseClass and its descendants are what I would consider persistent data transfer objects. They store their data in a class specific format.

The closest I can come to describing MyOtherBaseClass and its descendants would be unidirectional data mappers[[PoEAA]](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) but they mix a little business logic in as well.

The database only holds enough information to locate the objects and track their status.

Comment: In what way do `MyOtherClass1`, `MyOtherClass2` and the others differ from each other?

Comment: They all descend from the same base class but each overrides the methods of the base class with different implementations. I realize the two class hierarchies are tightly coupled. This is legacy code, afterall.

Comment: @codeelegance: ok, I was thinking that perhaps generics could be of use, but that is probably not the case then.

Comment: Whenever I see lots of type testing like that I suspect that the code is suffering from a lack of multiple virtual dispatch in the language. Does the visitor pattern solve your problem elegantly?

Comment: It's hard to say because there are no information about how MyOtherClass1, ... and MyClass1, ... are connected to each other. Maybe you can try to give a less stripped-down example? Most preferable would be an object oriented approach, but the table driven approach as well an approach with reflection are possible.

Comment: @Eric - Hmmmm... whenever I see the visitor pattern, I suspect that the code is suffering from a lack of algebraic data types and pattern matching in the language...

Comment: @kvb: Correct. "Patterns" are invented to provide a standardized solution to a problem space that is *not* already baked into the language. No one tries to do the "local variable pattern" or the "method pattern" or the "object pattern" in C# because they're already there. If C# already had multiple dispatch, say, then there'd be no need for the visitor pattern to make double dispatch work.

Answer (score 5):

Could you consider having an abstract method `generateOtherObject()` in the base class for `MyClass1`, `MyClass2`, etc. which is overriden in each derived class to create a new object of the relevant type?

Comment: Why do you assume MyClass1, MyClass2 share a common base class?

Comment: @leppie, actually his assumption is correct. MyClass* all descend from one base class and MyOtherClass* all descend from another base class.

Answer (score 2):

Another proposal may be to use a **builder**.

The one belows relies on a Dictionary which, for each type, describes the building action to be performed to generate a new instance (which should be easier to maintain than a if-else/switch statement).

Provided MyOtherClass1, MyOtherClass2 all derrive from `MyOtherBaseClass`, the following code may help you:

```
    public class YourTypeBuilderBuilder
    {
        private readonly static IDictionary<Type, Func<object, MyOtherBaseClass>> builderMap = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object, MyOtherBaseClass>>();

        static YourTypeBuilderBuilder()
        {
            /* Here is described the specific behavior 
            of the building of the requested type */

            builderMap.Add(typeof(MyClass1), obj => new MyOtherClass1((MyClass1)obj));
            builderMap.Add(typeof(MyClass2), obj => new MyOtherClass2((MyClass2)obj));
            builderMap.Add(typeof(MyClass3), obj => new MyOtherClass3((MyClass3)obj));
        }

        public static MyOtherBaseClass Build<T>(T input)
        {
            Func<object, MyOtherBaseClass> typeBuilder;
            bool hasTypeBeenFound = builderMap.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out typeBuilder);

            if (!hasTypeBeenFound)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid parameter.", typeof(T)));
            }

            // Let's build the requested type
            MyOtherBaseClass obj = typeBuilder(input);

            return obj;
        }
    }
```

Then your calling code would turn into

```
myOtherObject = YourTypeBuilder.Build(myObject);
```